# Which With a Logical Vector Returning Integer(0)

Tags: r

A little perplexed by this. I have a logical vector as such:

```
logical_vec <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
```

I am interested in capturing the indices of this logical vector so that I can subset another R object. For example, if I am interested in the position of the `TRUE` element, I thought I would use this:

```
which(TRUE, logical_vec) 
[1] 1
```

But when trying to find which index is `FALSE`, I get an `integer(0)` error.

```
which(FALSE, logical_vec)
integer(0)
```

Does which only return conditions that satisfy as TRUE or am I doing something incorrect here?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you want? Note that you supply a second argument `arr.ind`, which is not what you want.

```r
logical_vec <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
which(logical_vec == TRUE)
#> [1] 1
which(logical_vec == FALSE)
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: OOF! Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do. I'm not sure why I assumed I could just put the logical argument I'm trying to search against, alongside the vector. Thank you - I'll accept this when the time constraint runs out.

Answer (score 2):

`which` takes a single argument for 'x' and by passing two arguments, it takes the first one as 'x' and second argument by default is `arr.ind = FALSE`.  According to `?which`

> which(x, arr.ind = FALSE, useNames = TRUE)

where

> x - a logical vector or array. NAs are allowed and omitted (treated as if FALSE).

```
which(FALSE)
integer(0)
```

We may need to concatenate (`c`) to create a single vector instead of two arguments

```
which(c(FALSE, logical_vec))
[1] 2
```

---

Also, there is no need to do `==` on a logical vector - `which` by default gets the postion index of logical vector and if we need to negate, use `!`

```
which(logical_vec)
[1] 1
which(!logical_vec)
[1] 2
```

Comment: THANK you very much for the last tidbit. I always forget about that. I find myself doing things like `if (isTRUE(logical_element)` or `if(logical_element == TRUE)` rather than just `if (logical_element)` ect.

Comment: @bioinformatics2020 Probably, you thought that the first argument should take a negate argument in `which` and that resulted in the confusion